# Merging two accounts: may this be considered serial upvoting?

Tags: discussion, voting, accounts, duplicate-accounts

I have two accounts and perhaps they'll get merged in future.

On my other account I have voted more than 1000 times and I can't really remember for which questions and answers. So it may happen that with this account, I vote for the same question or answer accidentally.

At the time the accounts are merged, will those duplicate upvotes be considered as serial upvoting? I know people don't like the reversal of serial upvoting, but I also hardly see a chance to completely avoid it.

Maybe there's some good approach out there that I've not thought about yet.

One thing I could imagine is a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) in which I announce to SO that those accounts belong together. SO could then a) prevent me from voting twice and b) also prevent me from voting on my own questions (which is just a side effect; I will recognize my second me).

Comment: So you want to tell us you're working with both of these accounts simultaneously?

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion  Thomas did not say he upvoted himself. He said the two accounts may have voted on the same posts (of some other users), by negligence rather than malice.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: I know that upvoting myself isn't allowed and I do take care about it. I removed the ambiguous "usually" from the question.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I removed my obsolete comments :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When accounts are merged, duplicate votes are removed; your one account has just the one vote per post after all. This isn't quite the same thing as 'serial voting'.

You really should get those two accounts merged. Having two accounts is okay, provided you don't do anything with those two accounts you couldn't do with just one. Voting twice for posts or voting for your own posts are things you cannot do if you had just the one account!

Comment: So you think I shouldn't vote with the second account at all?

Comment: If you could otherwise not remember what posts you already voted on with the other, that may be prudent.